# Posterior distribution of the parameter knowing the prior

Tags: distributions, self-study, prior, gamma-distribution, posterior

I have exponentially distributed probability of event $E$

$$P(E|a) = a \exp(-aE),$$

where $a$ is the rate parameter of the exponential distribution.

Now the probability distribution for $a$ is a Gamma distribution with parameters $d$ and $b$

$$P(a|d,b) =  b^d  a^{d-1}  \exp(-ba) / \Gamma(d)$$

Knowing the prior distribution over $a$ and the likelihood over $E$, $P(E|a)$, how do I derive the posterior distribution for $a$?

I think (not sure!) that it should of the form $P(a|E,d,b)$. I also think that the result should be a standard probability distribution.

Comment: Is this for some subject?

Comment: Since this is standard bookwork. Please read the [tag-wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for the `self-study` tag. If it applies (if, for example, this is work for some subject), could you add the tag to your post (I suggest removing the `parameterization` tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Bayes' theorem, the posterior is proportional to the prior $\times$ the likelihood.

That is,

$$P(a|E,d,b)\propto P(E|a) P(a|d,b)$$

(which you should be able to show for yourself). When you take the product and collect like terms, you get something that will be a density for $a$, up to a multiplicative constant.

If you simplify that result and can recognize that density (I call it *playing 'spot the density'*), you can identify the parameters of the density you recognize and so work out the constant required to make it a density, at which point you have the complete posterior density.

In this case it has a nice simple form, that of a density I can say with some certainty you're already aware of.

---

Since the OP has clearly got the complete answer I will outline an approach to this question for future reference. (It's possible to do it a bit more formally than this.)

\begin{eqnarray}
P(a|E,d,b)&\propto& P(E|a) P(a|d,b)\quad \text{ (from Bayes' Theorem)}\\
 &\propto& a\exp(−aE) \cdot b^da^{d−1}\exp(−ba)/\Gamma(d)\\
 &\propto&  a^{d}\exp(−\{b+E\}a)\\
 &\propto&  a^{d^*-1}\exp(−b^*a)
\end{eqnarray}

where $d^* = d+1$ and $b^*=b+E$. This is clearly of the same gamma form that we started with in the prior, but with different shape and rate parameters.

If required, it's a simple matter to write down the constants needed to make it a proper density.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification, this is actually what I did, just needed reassuring that I am on the right track:)

Comment: I've multiplied the two but having a trouble detecting a distribution. Is it also Gamma?

Comment: I got ( (b^d) * a^d * e^(-a(b+E)) )/ Г(d)

Comment: Oh yeah, the exponential is a*exp(-ax) and this one is x^d*exp(-ax), right? I' m not sure I know a distribution of this form.

Comment: if I do the same operation on the prior (droping the constants) I get a^(d-1)*exp(-b*a) which very similar to what I got for the posterior. but I'm afraid to make any conclusions now.

Comment: So it is gamma.

Comment: b * is b + E and d* is d+1

Comment: Perfect. I guess I can write an answer now.

Comment: Thank you again, very helpful and you are a good teacher.